# Change the font of form and usercontrol( .frm and .ctl ) at runtime

Tags: user-controls, vb6, fonts, controls

I have a VB 6 Add-in that adds all the projects to a project group, iterates through each of the component of those projects, and if a form or usercontrol is found then changes its properties.

The properties are defined by the user. If user wants to change the height of all the forms or usercontrol then the code snippet is as follows

```
Private Sub Update_ButtonClick()
  '..declaring all the variables here

  ' VBInstance is initialized to VBIDE.VBE when the add-in is loaded

  For Index = 1 To projCount
    compoCount = VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents.Count
    For jIndex = 1 To compoCount

      csFileName = VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).name
      componentType = VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).Type

      If componentType = VBIDE.vbext_ct_VBForm Or componentType = VBIDE.vbext_ct_UserControl Then '.frm or .ctl         
        VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).Properties(propChange).Value = propvalue 'changing the property
        VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).SaveAs csFileName 'Saving the file
      End If
    Next jIndex
  Next Index
End Sub
```

Whenever I give the Properties name as `Font`, I get the error

> Runtime error '425' Invalid Object use

I have tried `PropertyBag.WriteProperty` from http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson13/p20.html but it does not serve my purpose.

Is there any way out to set the `Font` property of a control or form?

When I open the ctl or form in notepad, I cannot find the `Font` property in it so I cannot use text replacement here.

Can anyone help?

Updated Code :

```
Private Sub Update_ButtonClick()
    Dim fobject As New StdFont
    fobject.Name = "Arial"
    Set propvalue = fobject
    For Index = 1 To projCount
     compoCount = VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents.Count
     For jIndex = 1 To compoCount
      csFileName = VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).Name
      componentType = VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).Type
      If componentType = 5 Or componentType = 8 Then 
       VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).Properties("Font").Value=  propvalue
      VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).SaveAs csFileName 
      End If
       Next jIndex
     Next Index 
End Sub
```

And the error that i got is

```
Run-time error '425':
Invalid object use
```

Comment: Properties may not be listed in the form file if they have their default value (or in the case of the Font property, the same as their parent)

Comment: when i change the property and save the form and then open as text file , i was able to see the `Font` property..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Font` property is an object, not an simple intrinsic value. You'll need to use `Set` with an appropriate `StdFont` object assigned to `propvalue`.

Alternatively, you can special case the font and just set the property's `.Name` property to the required font name.

Comment: I have tried `Dim fobject As New StdFont
fobject.Name = "Arial"

Set propvalue = fobject` and then `VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).Properties("Font").Value = propvalue`....but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: And the alternate method `VBInstance.VBProjects(Index).VBComponents(jIndex).Properties("Font.Name").Value = propvalue` gave error as `Object does not support this property or method`

Comment: There is no `Font.Name` property. I have no idea why the first one you tried failed. What was the error. Did you try using `fobject` instead of `propvalue` (Or made sure they are assigned correctly)

Comment: yes i used the `fobject` instead of `propvalue` it didn't work out. I got the same error as before. `Object Does not support this property`

Comment: Can you update your question or post your updated code somewhere. The error message doesn't tie up with what you say you're doing.

Comment: @karthikkumar24 You haven't used `Set` where you assign it to the property.

Comment: @karthikkumar24 Have you tested it yet? Any further comments? If it works, can you pelase accept it as the answer and delete any superflous comments. Thanks.

Comment: I have used `Set` but i get `Object doesn't support this property method` error

Comment: @karthikkumar24 Can you then show your update code again as you aren't in the latest sample you've given, which is borne out by the error message.